# amfphp cant connect to gateway.php

Tags: php, flash, apache-flex

Hi im trying to use amfphp but after I downloaded the package and unzip it
i have create virtualhost named `ampf.pl` but when I go to `ampf.pl/browser`
I get

```
(mx.rpc::Fault)#0
  errorID = 0
  faultCode = "Client.Error.MessageSend"
  faultDetail = "Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Failed"
  faultString = "Send failed"
  message = "faultCode:Client.Error.MessageSend faultString:'Send failed' faultDetail:'Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Failed'"
  name = "Error"
  rootCause = (Object)#1
    code = "NetConnection.Call.Failed"
    description = "HTTP: Failed"
    details = "http://ampf.pl/gateway.php/"
    level = "error"
```

Edit:

I was using old version of amfphp 1.9 which is not working under php 5.4, It should be amfphp 2.1

Comment: can you check if your http server up and running, if yes than copy and paste the URL you have put in RemoteService URL in browser and check if it is pointing to getway.php file.

Comment: If i point directly to `gateway.php` my server can see it. And address is like above `ampf.pl/browser`

Comment: 1. you should point to root folder of gateway.php   ex:http://ampf.pl/.  2. Did you defined your Service class endpoint and do you have any service php class under http://ampf.pl/services/ ? 3. Please post your amfphp file structure and your AS3 service declaration

Answer (score 0):

In Amfphp 2 and higher there are no file such "gateway.php" it use "index.php".
So you have to provide path pointing to directory where you unzipped it.